"Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs." — "Scarlet with rage" modifies "she", so adjectives can modify pronouns?
collinsdictionary.com:
(1) Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs.
I thought adjectives can modify personal pronouns only in short phrases like "poor me" or "lucky you". But in this example "scarlet with rage" seems to modify "she". In this regard, I have some questions:
Is "scarlet with rage" an adjective phrase?
Does "scarlet with rage" function as the modifier of "she"?
If not, could you help me please to parse this phrase?

Adjective phrases can modify pronouns, sometimes. But it's complicated. Look at the comments on "Influenza-crazed[,] he killed his family". (There's also a question on relative clauses modifying pronouns.)

"Scarlet with rage" is an adjective phrase, but it's a supplement, not a modifier. Its function is that of predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "she" (she is the one who was scarlet with rage) and adjunct because it's an optional item in clause structure.

Some would label this as an absolute construction, while others reserve that label for adjuncts of the kind 'Her face scarlet with rage, she swept ...'.

Exhausted, he flopped into the chair.  There, it is the pronoun he that is being modified. Contrast that with He flopped exhaustedly into the chair.

@Loviii. Are you clear now that "scarlet with rage" is an adjective phrase functioning not as a manner adjunct but as a predicative adjunct?

She looked pinkishly as she swept past her boss… Now that's what I call an adverb.


Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the
stairs.

"Scarlet with rage" is an adjective phrase, but it's a supplement (or appendage), not a modifier.
Its function is that of predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "she" (she is the one who was scarlet with rage) and adjunct because it's an optional item in clause structure.
But predicative adjuncts aren't restricted to AdjPs: you can also have PPs or NPs:

In a bad temper, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party.
A proud teetotaller, John stuck to water while the others drank
champagne.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What is the anchor of the supplement "Scarlet with rage"? Thanks.

@Loviii I would say that the anchor is "she".  Compare the predicative complement in "She was scarlet with rage".

It's not unheard of for an adjective to modify a pronoun:

Loving in truth and fain in verse my love to show,
That she, dear she, might take some pleasure of my pain,—
 Philip Sidney, Astrophil and Stella 1

There's also the movie title Despicable Me.
Then there are phrases like "royal we" and "generic you," but those are special cases, in that the sense would be clearer with quotation marks around the pronoun: "royal 'we.'"
So: yes, it's definitely possible, though very far from common in everyday discourse, to use an adjective to modify a pronoun. That said, I agree with the general tenor of the answers and comments here: scarlet with rage is an adjunct, and scarlet is not functioning as a stand-alone adjective.

"Scarlet with rage" can only be an adjective phrase since it has the adjective "scarlet" as head. I agree that it's an adjunct, though it's not adverbial since it doesn't describe how she swept past her employer but her appearance when she did so. For this reason, it is predicative since it relates to a predicand, i.e. "she"; hence the label 'predicative adjunct.

@BillJ I edited my answer in the light of your comment. Thanks!

Scarlet with rage is a shortened gerund-participial (where being was omitted):

[Being] scarlet with rage

This gerund-participial is functioning as an adjunct and it modifies the rest of your sentence. I would classify it as an adjunct of reason or accompaniment.
A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (Rodney Huddleston & Geoffrey K. Pullum) analyses the sentence:

Following the manual, we tried to figure out how to assemble the unit.

saying that

Following is predicator in a gerund-participial clause functioning as adjunct; this clause itself has no overt subject, but an understood subject is retrievable from the subject of the main clause: the sentence implies that WE were following the manual. (see pp. 135-136)

In the same way, your sentence implies that SHE is scarlet with rage, but the gerund-participial clause does not modify the pronoun she.

Your excerpt is from "A Student's Introduction to English Grammar, First Edition, 2005". Here is the second one, 2022, if need be.

No, Fev. "Scarlet with rage" is an adjective phrase, not a shortened clause, but it's a supplement (appendage), not a modifier. Its function is that of predicative adjunct: predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "she" (she is the one who was scarlet with rage) and adjunct because it's an optional item in clause structure.

@fev. You mentioned A Student' Introduction to English Grammar. Predicative adjuncts are dealt with in that book on p119 [1.7].

@Loviii SIEG 1st edition explains predicative adjuncts on p119 [1.7] and in the 2nd edition on p102 (3rd line) and p171.

Being scarlet with rage in that sentence sounds like a reason. Being ill, he took to his bed.

There is no objective proof that scarlet with rage goes with she. It can very well describe how she stormed out of the room.  And there is such a thing as a fronted adverbial. See my answer. Compare: In a huff, she stormed out of the room.

COMPARE THESE THREE before reading this answer. If you think they are the same, don't bother with the answer:

Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs.

Scarlet with rage, she was completely alienated at that moment.

In a huff, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs.


The answers assume that "scarlet with rage" means: Very angrily in the first, and very angry in the second.
"scarlet with rage" can be an answer to that old adverbial idea:
How did she sweep past her employer? Hmm?
Like Fumble Fingers said: she swept past angrily. angrily=scarlet with rage. No "being" at all.
Why? Because colors are not in adverbial form, so you need that old friend "with" to make them function adverbially:
green with envy
blue with cold
black with ill humour
white with fear [and so on for other colors]

She glared at him green with envy over the award. How did she glare at him? She glared at him enviously.
The children stumbled into the house blue with cold. How did they enter? Blue with cold not hot with fever.

If you say "The children were blue with cold" and that therefore, it is adjectival, yes, it would be. But if you say: They stumbled in in freezing condition. the phrase in freezing condition describes how they stumbled. So, in the presence of dynamic verbs, I'd favor calling these adverbials.
To answer the question, this:

Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs. is adverbial and describes how she swept past her employer.

WHEREAS:
She was scarlet with rage when she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs. is adjectival and describes "she" (the pronoun that is the subject of the sentence) after a linking verb "was".
And just to really nail home the point:
She turned scarlet with rage when he gave her the news. is adverbial based on what I explained above.
These are also called adverbial adjuncts (the ones above with strong verbs), specifically here of manner (how). adverbial adjuncts _ of manner
Merriam Webster: turn. Definition 6.
c

to cause to become of a specified nature or appearance turned him into
a frog embarrassment turned her face red

REFERENCE FOR A FRONTED ADVERBIAL:

Fronted Adverbials A fronted adverbial is a word, phrase or clause
that is used as an adverb, modifying a verb or a clause that comes
after it. The "fronted" part of the name means that it comes in front
of everything else. Adverbs themselves can be used as adverbials, but
many other types of words, phrases and clauses can be used in this
way, including prepositional phrases and subordinate clauses. What do
fronted adverbials do? These phrases are useful in descriptive
writing, as they can easily describe where, when and how an action
occurred.
Basically, fronted adverbials are phrases or words at the start of a sentence which are used to describe the action that follows. They can
be used as sentence starters. Normally, a comma is used after an
adverbial, although there are still plenty of exceptions to this
rule.

fronted adverbial

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Scarlet with rage, she swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs.

She swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs while/and she was scarlet with rage.
Scarlet with rage is adjectival but, with the omitted conjunction, it has the effect of a sentence adverb modifying She swept past her employer and stormed up the stairs
